# Splitting a very large string (few GBs) into rows in PySpark or Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a text file a few GBs in size, which consists of a single string with the following delimiters:

1. Row delimiter - `#@#@#`
2. Column delimiter - `'~'` (including the single quotes)

Example - `Aditya G'~'1991#@#@#Sri C'~'1989#@#@#...`

The above example basically shows 2 rows like this:

| name | year |
| --- | --- |
| Aditya G | 1991 |
| Sri C | 1989 |

My objective is to create a PySpark Dataframe like the above example from this file. But due to the size of the file, the first step (i.e. splitting single string into rows) itself is proving very difficult. I tried using `split` in PySpark:

```
rdd = spark.read.text(file_path)
rdd1 = rdd.select(split(rdd.value, '#@#@#', -1).alias('rows'))
rdd1.show(4, False)
```

But I am getting an `OutOfMemory: Java heap space` error for above code. Which means that the file size is too large for Spark to ingest the string whole and then apply the pattern.

1 way out would be to go character by character and check for `#@#@#` and split the string into a list of strings in Python. Then I can convert this list of strings into a dataframe and go from there. But it seems like a cumbersome process that may also be very slow as I am not using Spark's distributed architecture.

Are there any ideas that will speed up this process?

Comment: You might be able to use pyspark's CSV loader, and specifying the `sep` and `lineSep` options. This should be relatively quick vs. processing things in python.
The only wrinkle is it doesn't support multi-character line-separators, but depending on your data you might be able to get away with using `#` or `@` as a line separator, and then tidy up the result after.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you would really think that this is supported by the language or the standard library, but I did not find anything. You do not want to read you input one character at a time, because that would be terribly inefficient.

What you need, instead, is to create a double buffering reader function. You read the file in fixed size chunks, adding each chunk to the back of a records buffer after you read it. Then, you look for the first record delimiter in the buffer, and yield all text up to it, then removing the text from the front of the buffer, together with the record delimiter.

```py
from io import IOBase, StringIO

# Double buffering reader
def read_records(stream: IOBase, delim: str, block_size=128):
    buffer: str = ""
    delim_len = len(delim)
    while (chunk := stream.read(block_size)):
        buffer += chunk
        while (pos := buffer.find(delim)) != -1:
            yield buffer[:pos]
            buffer = buffer[pos + delim_len:]
    if buffer:
        yield buffer

# Small sample text (note that there are no new-lines in this text)
text = (
    "Aditya G'~'1991#@#@#"
    "Sri C'~'1989#@#@#"
    "Aditya G'~'1991#@#@#"
    "Sri C'~'1989#@#@#"
    "Aditya G'~'1991#@#@#"
    "Sri C'~'1989#@#@#"
    "Aditya G'~'1991#@#@#"
    "Sri C'~'1989#@#@#"
    "last-line"
)

# Iterate over records and print them
with StringIO(text) as stream:
    for line in read_records(stream, "#@#@#", 4):
        print(line.split("'~'"))
```

This takes care of splitting your file into records. Splitting the records into fields is much simpler, as the records are small enough to be processes in memory. You can simply use the `split` string method.

Note that I made the size of the block you read default to 128, which is good for this tiny example. For the real-life case, you would want the block size to be larger than the maximum record size, and at any rate, not too small. Several kilobytes would probably be a good size.